# Reading shapefiles data with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shapefile

I have just started using ESRI API to process GIS data (shapefiles), I am also using this code (https://github.com/mraad/spark-shp) to read the data using spark (running scala code).

My question is, how can we extract polygons from a shapefile, since I can't find it anywhere in the documentation
When I read the Shapefile I get only an RDD with Points not Polygons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probable worth raising an issue on the GitHub project in question with your query. The maintainers are the most suited to answering your question, and it can help them improve their documentation.

From what I can see, you should be getting a `DataFrame` rather than `RDD`. So perhaps you're using a lower level method than is expected. [This](https://github.com/mraad/spark-shp/blob/52d2da98395acaf260af96d528a71486d8919191/src/main/scala/com/esri/spark/shp/package.scala#L48) extension method on `DataFrameReader` suggests to me that you should be using the `shp` method to load your files and get back a `DataFrame`. Within the same file there is also another `shp` extension method that appears in that projects [tests](https://github.com/mraad/spark-shp/blob/52d2da98395acaf260af96d528a71486d8919191/src/test/scala/com/esri/spark/shp/ShpSuite.scala#L45) showing loading of a file like so:

```scala
val results = sparkSession
  .sqlContext
   .shp(path)
```

You'll need to import the package/implicits to access these methods.

Comment: That was helpful, also I had to create a method to transform these points coordinates to polygons, then use other libraries to check if the polygon contains the coordinates i am checking